# In irssi, how do I display previous chats of current chan, or current user if in bitblee?

Tags: irc, irssi

When I reopen irssi, I'd like to display - easily and from inside irssi - previous conversations of a chan, or a query window with specific user (mostly for private conversation in bitlbee).

I can obviously find logs, it's set in my ~/.irssi/config :

```
autolog_path = "~/.irclogs/$tag/$0.log";
```

but i can't display them in active and corresponding irssi window.

That seems a basic chat feature I'd like to enjoy.

Comment: Indeed, i like that feature as well (i think its very important, esp. if you have quite a lot of personal querys).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using a script for this, at least this does do log playback in private chats:

http://scripts.irssi.org/scripts/queryresume.pl

By changing `return unless (ref $witem && $witem->{type} eq 'QUERY');` 
to `#return unless (ref $witem && $witem->{type} eq 'QUERY');` this can also be used for playback of Chatlogs regarding irc-channels as well.

Comment: Thanks ! That does the trick, even if it's basic.  
For the record, you can increase the resume (line 61) from irssi :  
`/set queryresume_lines xx`

If anyone knows better, please share !